# Why don't determiners modify nouns but predeterminer modify nouns

Tags: determiners, predeterminers

determiner (plural determiners)

(grammar) A member of a class of words functioning in a noun phrase to identify or distinguish a referent without describing or modifying it

predeterminer (plural predeterminers)

(grammar) The function of a phrase that precedes a determiner in a noun phrase and modifies the head noun.

Why don't determiners modify nouns but
predeterminer modify nouns?

Comment: A noun can have only one determiner. The predeterminers are inside the NP but outside (external to) the head nominal, where they function as modifiers. Cf. "Both [her sons] went to university", where "her" is the determiner in the bracketed nominal, and "both" is a predeterminer modifier.

Comment: @BillJ so Is a predeterminer an adjective?

Comment: Sometimes but not always: predeterminers may be determimatives like "both" or adjectives like "such" in "such a disaster", or adverbs like "even" in "even the children". Incidentally, determin**ative** is the part of speech, while 'determin**er**"' and "predetermin**er**" are functions -- note the spelling difference.

Comment: There are three types of determiners predeterminer central determiners postdeterminers  you mean predeterminer we talk about is not one of them?

Comment: No: the predeterminers and the so-called postdeterminers are modifiers, not determiners as such.

Comment: @BillJ That's why plural nouns don't take 'one' because numerals are determiners so are not modifiers that's right?

Comment: The cardinal numerals "one", "two", "three" etc. are determinatives, "One" is incompatible with non-count singular nouns.